# A "multidimensional d" to include uncertainty in distance matrices

Tags: clustering, effect-size, distance

We're all familiar with Cohen's *d*, difference between means divided by pooled standard deviation. Is it valid to incorporate the concept to create a "deviation adjusted distance matrix"? Euclidean distance is a multidimensional extension of the distance between two points. So, if one were to propagate standard deviations by taking the square roots of the sums of squared sd, could one then divide the Euclidean matrix by the (sort of) pooled sd matrix and have a "multidimensional *d*"?

Why do this? Because I want to express distance in terms of standardized effect sizes rather than simply subtracting mean values.

Comment: Please search our site for "Mahalanobis distance."

Comment: Mahalanobis distance still presumes that each point has a specific and fixed location, not a location amd deviations.

Comment: I don't follow.  Cohen's *d* is a 1D Mahalanobis distance.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I can just update my report accordingly.